# VNC from Windows to Mac freezing constantly

Tags: mac-osx, windows-vista, vnc

I'm trying to VNC into an OSX 10.4.11 box from Vista using RealVNC and TightVNC. I can connect successfully, but after a minute or so my VNC window freezes completely, while on the Mac the AppleVncServer process starts eating up huge amounts of RAM (100Mb +) and CPU (40-50%) - but the Mac doesn't freeze. When this happens no-one can VNC in anymore until the AppleVncServer process is restarted.

I have trawled through all the available options on the VNC clients I'm using and I don't see anything obvious that would cause this behaviour. I'd be grateful for any insights into this.

Darko

UPDATE: After more troubleshooting it seems this happens only when I to a copy on Vista. As soon as a copy operation is performed VNC freezes up. Note that copy paste inside VNC works fine....

Comment: Reflecting back on this, it should probably have been moved to superuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with clipboard incompatability.

For Example a TightVNC connection configuration file will contain disableclipboard=0.  Change that value to 1 and your VNC server on the MAC side will not crash.

Comment: I confirmed Evan's answer - it's the clipboard thing. i'm trying winxp to macosx

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems in the past with RealVNC and TightVNC.

Have you tried UltraVNC yet?  This solved the problem for us.  Not sure why.

Comment: thanks i'll give it a go. also troubleshooted some more and updated question

Comment: sorry mate, Ultra VNC wont even log on. According to UltraVNC no-one uses passwords longer than 8 characters

Comment: Very strange.  We're using UltraVNC with an 11 character password.

Comment: +1 for UltraVNC, RealVNC and TightVNC sorely need improvements...

Comment: +1. Switching to UltraVNC and turning off the clipboard option fixed this problem for me.  UltraVNC looks way better than RealVNC too.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with Tiger except I was trying to remote in from a Windows XP machine. I tried a variety of different clients, all with exactly the same results.

In the end I just turned off the VNC server included with Mac OS X and installed Vine Server instead. Never had a problem with Vine Server, no matter which client I used on the Windows PC.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/

I should probably mention, when I upgraded to Leopard, I went back to using the included VNC server. It seems to be more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark - As you are saying it is to do with file copy, possibly try running vnc viewer as administrator or disable UAC as it could be a permission issue.